# Lipschitz constant of $\frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} x$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x \neq \vec{0}$, I want want to find the Lipschitz constant of the map $f(x) = \frac{\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2} x$

In other words I want to find $K$ such that $\| f(x) - f(y) \| \leq K \|x-y\|$.

Comment: What norm are you taking in the Lipschitz inequality? The norm $\|\cdot\|_2$?

Comment: Ideally any norm, but I guess we can assume the L2 norm in the proof.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to show this using only the definition of Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: Function $f$ at $0$ should take the value $0$, I guess. I showed that $\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq a(x) \|x-y\| + \|y\| |a(x) - a(y)|$, where $a(x) = \|x\|_\infty/\|x\|_2$. I plotted it and it seems to be Lipschitz. I then showed that $|a(x)-a(y)|\leq \|\hat{x} - \hat{y}\|$, where $\hat{x} = x/\|x\|_\infty$. Bad news: $\hat{x}$ is not Lipschitz. This doesn't mean $f$ is not Lipschitz - it just means we cannot prove it this way. For what it's worth, I'm posting my attempt here.

Comment: Some useful inequalities that might help solve the problem: (i) $\|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|x\|_\infty$, (ii) \|x-\hat{x}\| \leq \|\hat{y} - \hat{x}\| (because $\hat{x}$ is the $\|\cdot\|_2$-projection of $x$ on the unit sphere), (iii) triangle inequality. Let me know if you figure out how to answer this.

Comment: The first inequality $\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq a(x) \|x-y\| + \|y\| |a(x) - a(y)|$ is the furthest point I was able to get to. You mentioned some directions to take the proof further, however I am not able to make any progress. From what I can tell you are saying that it is not possible to do a direct proof. Is that right?

Comment: @fornit I'm not sure. I haven't been able to prove or disprove it either. It feels like it should be Lipschitz, though (at least locally, which should be OK for your application especially if the constraints of your optimization problem are compact).